# Selenium IDE File error: Unrecognized path File XML

Tags: xml, selenium, path

In my script I work with files .xml and selenium reads this files. I have to include the path (until the file). In my local machine it works perfectly.

But I want to make the file available within the network (at a server machine). When I insert the path in the script and run it, selenium shows the following error:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: Error: Error while fetching url 'file:///xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/BD.xml' details: [Exception... "File error: Unrecognized path" nsresult: "0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js -> file:///C:/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/user-extensions.js.includeCommand4IDE.js?1389101013405 :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 83" data: no]. fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js -> file:///C:/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/user-extensions.js.includeCommand4IDE.js?1389101013405, lineNumber -> 85, columnNumber -> 6
```

How can I fix it? Does it happen because of the size of path?

Thanks.

Comment: Please proof-read your question before asking - there are many simply mistakes, which I guess you could have easily spotted (and no; I am not a native speaker myself and make mistakes all the time. It is more about the effort, it is not about being 100% correct). Regarding your problem: Seems like the `file://` protocol isn't supported, so you might try another protocol, e.g. `http://`

Comment: Thanks for help, but I tried with both protocols and shows the error. With protocol http:// shows the following error: [error] Unexpected Exception: Error: Error while fetching http:///xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/BD.xml server response has status = 404, Not Found. fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js -> file:///C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Selenium/user-extensions.js.includeCommand4IDE.js?1389110352427, lineNumber -> 88, columnNumber -> 0 I am new in selenium, sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: HTTP status code 404 obviously states that there is no document at the given address. It also says `Not found`.

Comment: I know that. With "HTTP" protocol doesn´t work. In my local machine it works perfectly with protocol "FILE" Thanks for help